# Jquery hide/ show elemnt on hover

Tags: jquery

I want to show some element on hover and hide it on mouseleave. I know it's common problem and usually it's made by something like this:

```
jQuery(".show_it").hover(
    function () {
        jQuery(".my_text").show();
    }, 
    function () {
        jQuery(".my_text").hide();
    }
);
```

But this way element .my_text is blinking on that action (quick changes between display:none and block) even if I have a mouse cursor in the rest position. Element .show_it has width and height 30px and also I tried to set high value of z-index but it had no effect. Anyone thougts where is problem?

Comment: It's not the same element. I want hover to hover on element $(".show_it") and than show elemnent  $(".my_text"),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine as such with this in your HTML:

```
<div class="show_it">Hover over this</div>

<div class="my_text" style="display:none;">And then this will show up</div>
```

And then with this javascript:

```
$(".show_it").hover( 
    function() { $(".my_text").show(); }, 
    function() { $(".my_text").hide(); } 
);
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmrk25bf/1/) that shows it working

Comment: @PavelNěmec Well, then, probably best to also post your html.  Maybe even try entering the html I used instead of yours and see if that works.  Good luck with the problem solving...

Comment: The problem was caused by window.setInterval function which includes some function to change content.

Comment: @PavelNěmec Seeing as how I proved the basic code will work and provided working examples, can I get an upvote and possibly accepted?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.show_it').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.my_text').show();
   }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.my_text').hide();
   });

});
```

Use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` jQuery methods instead

Comment: Unfortunatelly it's exactly the same.